# Is it possible to leave some apps in the internal memory while using S2E?

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage

Well, is it possible? I have a Galaxy Ace with the official CyanogenMod ROM. I only have a class 4 micro SD card and is using the SD Speed Increase app.

I was wondering if I could leave some apps (like handcent sms, go launcher ex, etc) in the internal memory while retaining other apps in the sd-ext partition. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

S2E moves the whole applicator folder to your ext partition. If you want to move specific applications you need to use something else.

Something else in this case can be [Link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en). You can pick apps and even data to move.